# Pug: How to add interpolation for id?

Tags: pug

Originally the code is like this

```
.tab-content
    #session1.tab-pane.active(role='tabpanel')
        table#myTable1.table.table-striped.table-bordered(cellspacing="0" width="100%")
    #session2.tab-pane(role='tabpanel')
        table#myTable2.table.table-striped.table-bordered(cellspacing="0" width="100%")
    #session3.tab-pane(role='tabpanel')
        table#myTable3.table.table-striped.table-bordered(cellspacing="0" width="100%")
    #session4.tab-pane(role='tabpanel')
        table#myTable4.table.table-striped.table-bordered(cellspacing="0" width="100%")
```

I want to convert it into loop. How do I do with the id for each tab?

```
.tab-content
    each num in sessionsNumber
        if num == 1
            #session+num.tab-pane.active(role='tabpanel')
                table#myTable+num.table.table-striped.table-bordered(cellspacing="0" width="100%")
        else
            #session+num.tab-pane(role='tabpanel')
                table#myTable+num.table.table-striped.table-bordered(cellspacing="0" width="100%")
```

This is wrong. I have try serveral options and can't get it right.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically set the id, use the id attribute syntax `(id='myId')` instead of the id shorthand `#myId`:

```
.tab-content
    each num in sessionsNumber
        if num == 1
            #session1.tab-pane.active(role='tabpanel')
                table.table.table-striped.table-bordered(id=`myTable${num}`,cellspacing='0', width='100%')
        else
            .tab-pane(id=`session${num}`, role='tabpanel')
                table.table.table-striped.table-bordered(id=`myTable${num}`, cellspacing='0', width='100%')
```

Here's a cleaner approach to adding that "active" class for the first tab pane using a [javascript ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), so that you don't have to repeat the table markup:

```
.tab-content
    each num in sessionsNumber
        .tab-pane(id=`session${num}`, class= (1 == num) ? 'active' : '', role='tabpanel')
            table.table.table-striped.table-bordered(id=`myTable${num}`, cellspacing='0', width='100%')
```

Don't forget to comma separate attributes in pug.